# Box Shadow disappears from the table header after scrolling CSS

Tags: css

I have box shadow on `thead` element, but it disappears after scrolling.

CSS:

```css
thead {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #e1e5ee;
}

thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  background: white !important;
}
```

Before:
[image]

After scrolling:
[image]

Comment: Looks like the thead element keeps scrolling, but the th elements sticks to the top. Have you tried to use the position sticky on the thead element instead of the th?

Comment: Yes, that way it scrolls like any other row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the shadow is on the `thead`, but the `th` elements are the ones that are sticky.

Try changing your style definitions to this:

```
thead tr {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #e1e5ee;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

thead th {
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  background: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it works as expected. Thank you!